# SQL Server Left join on two parameters not returning the not found on B table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two tables: "addToCart" and "order2":

addToCart - Users that added Product to the cart

order - Users that bought the product

In both tables I also have the product category.

**AddToCart**

```
UserID   ProductCategory   Date
-----------------------------------
001id    ProductCategory1  02/24/2020 10:00 AM
001id    ProductCategory2  02/24/2020 11:00 AM
001id    ProductCategory2  02/24/2020 11:40 AM
001id    ProductCategory3  02/24/2020 12:40 PM
```

**Order2**

```
UserID   ProductCategory   Date
-----------------------------------
001id    ProductCategory1  02/24/2020 11:00 AM
001id    ProductCategory2  02/24/2020 11:30 AM
```

I need to get the users that abandoned the cart in every ProductCategory. To achieve this, I look to users that added to cart and not generate an order or the last addToCart for one ProductCategory is older than the order for that same ProductCategory.

So, everyday I run this query:

```
select 
  added.UserID,
  added.ProductCategory,
  max(added.[Date]) as addedDate
from addTocart added
left join order2 ord
on added.UserID = ord.UserID
  and added.ProductCategory = ord.ProductCategory
group by added.UserID, added.ProductCategory
having max(added.[Date]) > max(ord.[Date])
```

For what I know, if I do a left join between table A and table B (`on A.id = B.id`), I can bring rows from table A that doesn't have a match in table B.

But when I run this query with the two parameters in the on clause, the id001 for ProductCategory3 isn't returned. Can someone help identify why and want can I do to return the contacts that have added to cart some productCategory but, doesn't have the ordered this productCategory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi!**

I do not have any server at the moment, but maybe "having"
may have something like this:

```
having max(added.[Date]) > max(ord.[Date]) or IsNull(ord.[Date])
```

P. S.
I do not know the semantics of your developed query, but it looks like the problem is in that clause.